# Biblatex not printing citations

Tags: biblatex

For some reason `biblatex` isn't working properly.  It seems it can't reference the `.bib` file, and thus doesn't print the citations properly.  The strange thing is that I have an older `.tex` file that uses `biblatex` with the same sequence of commands, and it works.  For some reason this new one doesn't work.  In any case, here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{edrefs.bib}
\begin{document}
This is the main\footcite{Edg} text.\footcite[32]{SkilFR}
\cite{Edg}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the `.bib` file:

```
 @mvbook
  {Edg,
  AUTHOR = "Edgerton, Franklin",
  TITLE = "{Buddhist Hybrid Sanskrit Grammar and Dictionary}",
  VOLUMEs = 2,
  PUBLISHER = "Yale University Press",
  LOCATION = "New Haven",
  YEAR = 1953
  }

   @article
   {SkilFR,
   author = "Skilton, Andrew",
   title = "{Four Recensions of the Samādhirājasūtra}",
   journaltitle = "{Indo-Iranian Journal}",
  pages = "335--356",
  volume = 42,
  number = 4,
  year = 1999,
  publisher = "Klewer",
  location = "Netherlands"
  }
```

Comment: You did run biber? [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154767)

Comment: Ah, yes, that's what I forgot!  Stupid mistake.  In any case, I run it through biber, but I get these errors: 


This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)

The top-level auxiliary file: bibtest.aux

I found no \citation commands---while reading file bibtest.aux

I found no \bibdata command---while reading file bibtest.aux

I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file bibtest.aux

(There were 3 error messages)

Thanks!

Comment: You're obviously not running `biber` if you get a message saying *This is `bibtex`*...

Comment: OK, well what I do is switch my TeX editor to compile using BibTeX (rather that XeLaTeX).  This is what I have done in the past and it worked then.

Comment: You have requested `biblatex` with the `backend=biber` option. That means you have to compile using Biber and not BibTeX. Please refer to the second link Johannes posted above to find out how to configure you editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX.

Comment: `bibtex` and `biber` are two *different* programs for generating and sorting a bibliography, and if you set `biblatex` up to generate code for one of them (as you have done with `backend=biber`) you cannot use the other -- they are incompatible in that sense.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you.  That solved it.  I suppose I had changed the preferences of my editor back to using `bibtex` and forgotten that I needed to change it to `biber`.